# Chat in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want implement chat in SharePoint 2010

I need to develop the chat application in SharePoint 2010.
I need the Steps for Development and my requirement is that users should able to chat with each other

How can I achieve this scenario?

Please explain step by step.

Answer (score 6):

Fatima,

There are several options, some of them are discussed here:
[Instant Messaging options in SharePoint 2010](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Instant-Messaging-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

**LYNC WITH SHAREPOINT**
Most favourable is integrating Lync Server with SharePoint, if you want information about Microsoft Lync and its integration with SharePoint 2010
[Lync Server 2010 Resource Kit——SharePoint Integration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/drrez/archive/2011/04/04/microsoft-lync-server-2010-resource-kit-sharepoint-integration.aspx)

OrbitOne provides [Lync Presence and Chat Widget](http://www.orbitone.com/en/CodePlex/Pages/LyncPresenceChatWidget.aspx), with some work you can integrate this in SharePoint...

And this article talks about [SharePoint 2010 and Lync integration features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398806.aspx)

Another more information about Lync and SharePoint integration for your reference.
http://chamindasomathilaka.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/lync-sharepoint-integration-for-skill-based-search/ 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/drrez/archive/2011/04/27/lync-2010-exchange-2010-sharepoint-2010-and-office-2010-integration-part-2.aspx

**WINDOWS LIVE**
One that consumes Windows Live Id's [MSN] is shown here:
[How to Implement Live Chat in Sharepoint](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/05/how-to-implement-live-chat-in.html)

**OTHER OPEN SOURCE**
One of the codeplex project [SharePoint Chat](http://sharepointchat.codeplex.com/)

**THIRD PARTY**
There are some third party paid Chatting features available as:
[Lightning Chat Web Part](http://lightningtools.com/lightning-chat/)
[Micro Blog/Chat Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5810)
[SPP iChat](http://www.sharepointpowerpack.com/products/chat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout SharePoint Messenger on codeplex.

http://sharepointmessenger.codeplex.com/